# How to deal with a boss who is trying to make you quit

Tags: professionalism, work-environment, manager, romania

I work in company which does outsourcing to various clients.

My first project assigned was related to DHCP for a client which does network software. The implementation and testing took about 3 months (IPv4 and IPv6) at which point the client decided that it no longer needs a developer.

Instead of being assigned to another client, the company rotated me to another part of the initial project. I did a task related to logging and then went into vacation.

During vacation, my boss, who is also one of the co-founders of the company, established an interview for a project with another client. Bear in mind I was on vacation but had to have the interview because "the client is more important" and I never got reimbursed for the lost vacation day due to this interview.

When I got back into the office, the initial client decided that there is an extra team required for another part of the project so my boss assigned me to this new team. This is were the things got bad.

My boss did not want to give me a company laptop (it was taken from me before vacation). Only a set of generic credentials were provided and I had to use my own laptop to setup things. Meanwhile every other team member had been given a company laptop and their own set of credentials. I tried to access various client resources for 3 weeks because credentials were not working. My boss was yelling and making fun of me in meetings.

After this time I got a company laptop, one made in 2014! It was barely working, only 1 USB port and no touchpad. I was also prohibited from installing other OS on it, apparently it was setup just for me. Yelling and making fun of continued, while my task queue grew, I still had trouble with access to required resources.

Finally my boss gave in and I received a new laptop and a new set of credentials. Found out that the laptop and credentials were actually from a colleague who quit a day before. This colleague was on another part of the project, so I had to make tens of requests for access to required client resources.

By this time we were in december 2020. However I got sick with covid, along with 10 more colleagues who worked in the same office. At some point I got hospitalised as my condition was getting worse.

While I was in the hospital, I got a message from my boss requesting me to enter a meeting regarding the project, even if he knew that I was sick. This didn't sit well with me at all, but I respectfully declined which got him mad.

Just got back from medical leave and got yelled a for "not supporting the team while on leave", I was out for 3 weeks. Then came the time for task allocation, by my boss of course, guess who got the high risk and tight deadlines ones ?

Other things that my boss did:

- setting up meetings during lunch break or after work hours and then yelling at me for not participating
- calling on my personal phone after work hours just to tell me that I am stupid and got work to do
- moving task deadlines closer without asking
- general badmouthing me in front of colleagues

So, how to handle this devil?

Comment: "So, how to handle this devil?" What country are you in? Is there any reason why you didn't do the obvious yet and quit?

Comment: Why do you think he is picking on you in particular?

Comment: **>> why you didn't do the obvious yet and quit** 
Had an offer which was withdrew when I got sick with covid. Plus, if I quit I am not getting any benefits or medical insurance. If I get fired, then I am covered for 1 year by law.

Comment: **>> 2) finding a better job and quitting this one**
Until then my work life is pretty much hell.

Comment: **>> Why do you think he is picking on you in particular?**
Because they hired me for the DHCP stuff and I've done it so I am no longer of use to them. I've asked around my peers and found out that it is not the first time this happened in this company, they hire people for one job and when they finish, f*** them.

Comment: @gsucker and what country are you in? Since you are looking for actual handling it advice, not get a new job sort, we need to know that.

Comment: This really just sounds like a long-winded "I hate my boss" rant. I don't really see a usable question in here.

Comment: *If I get fired, then I am covered for 1 year by law.* Does this mean you can otherwise afford to be unemployed for a time as long as you’re fired?

Comment: **>>you can otherwise afford to be unemployed for a time as long as you’re fired** I wold not say "afford", but if you get fired then you get a small monthly allowance from the state and free medical insurance. Of course, I want to work and I am looking for a job currently, so I won't be stuck in that situation for too long.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul I am in a EU state called Romania.

Comment: @JoelEtherton I don't actually hate my boss, that would be an unnecessary waste of energy, however I don't like the way I am being treated.

Comment: @gsucker: That's great. That doesn't really change this from a rant into an actual question though (IMO).

Comment: @JoelEtherton How the fact that his boss is literally treating him different than his colleagues in a way that seems to be "setting him up for failure" be categorized as a rant ? A rant is someone complaining about random stuff, here we have serious facts.

Comment: @Walfrat: "facts"? You were present for these then? You're sure there's absolutely no other defining context or viewpoint that might make these into opinions? No. This is a long list of complaints followed by a "question" that answers itself. It practicality feeds into the axiom "People don't leave bad companies they leave bad bosses. "

Answer (score 16):

> *So, how to handle this devil ?*

I'm actually surprised to see you waited this long. There are more than 4 cases I can see that are independently reason enough for me to search for a new job and quit this one.

Polish your resume, find a new job, serve the notice period (if needed) and quit. This is not a workplace you (or anyone) would like to work in.

That said, whatever unjustified demands were made of you (and you complied), make a list of them. Prepare whatever documentation you can (even if it's late) for all these incidents you mentioned:

- Yelling / Making fun / Bullying
- Forcing / Demanding to work while you're on leave (medical or otherwise)
- Lack of proper support (planning / hardware etc) for getting the assigned works done on time

Once you submit the resignation, given the nature of your boss, they may try to prove your incompetence and get rid of you in any negative ways possible, so document whatever you can salvage from past incidents and everything from now on.

Answer (score 3):

You do two things. One is that you look for another job obviously, and as soon you have a signed contract, you give notice.

Two, you realise what kind of person that "boss" being is. That anything he does is not because you are doing something wrong, but because he is a lowlife. Make a game of it: Take as much money off him as you can, while delivering as little useful work as you possible can. You've been doing a good job at it without even trying, just with your boss being stupid.

(PS. I should have mentioned that I read about the "boss" being one of the company founders. If a company founder acts stupid, the company deserves anything they get. If the "boss" is some underling I'd think about inflicting damage to the boss only).

Answer (score 1):

Only thing you should do is find another job

As for boss`s behavior etc, IMHO, your location is paramount

You need to check with local employment laws regarding toxic workplace, bullying and verbal abuse.

I am sure by now you have a plethora of evidence to support your claim.

Answer (score 0):

Immediately begin searching for a new job, and hand in your notice as soon as (or even before) another opportunity materializes.

Meanwhile, don't completely stay reactive. Collect evidences (recordings, transcripts of their offense etc.) and keep them secure. Seek help from your local authorities and/or get a lawyer, hopefully there will be afforable legal help available in your perimeter. During this period, hold your breath and try your best to disengage. Avoid responding to these offenses anymore and follow your lawyer's advices.

Good luck defending yourself. Tough times call for tough decisions.

Answer (score 0):

Find a new job. Make sure you don't use your boss as a reference or even mention his name to any prospective employers. Only use co-workers or other management who you trust at the company. Don't try use a co-worker who is in any way friends/kissing up to your boss. Regardless of how nice they act.

When you give your notice your boss will probably terminate you 1 second later so be financially prepared or have your other job start date be immediate instead of delayed if you can.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like a textbook case of [Constructive Dismissal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_dismissal).  Basically, your company won't allow you to collect unemployment by firing you, but they also want to make your workplace as unbearable as possible so you'll quit.  Not sure if Romania has constructive dismissal laws, but you should look into it, and if they do (or something similar) then seek legal counsel.

Also, find a new job ASAP.

Comment: Unfortunately the law here does not define Constructive Dismissal, there was a huge lobby against it because the proposal came from a party which a huge part of romanians hate, talk about brainwash.

Comment: Welcome to why you should vote based on parties with good platforms and not based on social media or your friends' opinions.  Hopefully you've learned a valuable lesson (or if you've already learned this lesson, then it's a lesson you can teach to others using personal anecdotal experience).